# Custom Post Type / Two level deep taxonomy (cat. and subcat.) uri problem (error 404)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, 404-error, hierarchical

I've created a CPT named "decoration products"(productos decoración), the problem concerns to it CPT.

When for the first time I created "decoration products" CPT, I realized that it needed two level taxonomy uri structure. To visually illustrate it:

- `Root_domain/CPT name/` - This is a page that shows all "decoration products" CPT's posts.
- `Root_domain/CPT name/category` - This is an archive page that shows top level category's posts.
- `Root_domain/CPT name/category/subcategory` - This is an archive page that shows subcategory's posts.
- `Root_domain/CPT name/category/subcategory/post-title` - This is a post within a certain top category and subcategory.

I based on this post:

- wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types

to create two level taxonomy uri structure  for "decoration products" CPT. Anyway there were some fixes to do, for instance, double slash in the uri. I fixed it with this helpful post:

- wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75157/how-to-fix-a-double-slash-in-custom-permalinks-with-hierarchical-taxonomys

I create all my code based on above two posts and put it in functions.php. You can see it in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/uPpQ9qS3).

I thought, that everything works well until I’ve realized that there’re some problems with the manner that WordPress handle CPT top-categories and child-categories URIs. These are the problems:

**PROBLEM 1:**

This interior illumination's post:

```
Root_domain/productos-decoracion/iluminacion/iluminacion-interior/crea-ambientes-interior-acogedores
```

When I click on breadcrumb link “Iluminación interior” of this post, it must show “Iluminación interior” archive page, in the following uri:

```
Root_domain/productos-decoracion/iluminacion/iluminacion-interior
```

Instead of 404 Page not Found (Error 404: Página no encontrada).
If I change manually browser's uri to:

```
Root_domain/productos-decoracion/iluminacion-interior
```

404 Page not Found error disappear and everything works well.

If I remove `'hierarchical'=>true` from `'rewrite'` in `function my_taxonomies_product()` (you can find it above pastebin function.php code) and I click on breadcrumb link “Iluminación interior”, it shows archive page like I want but in the wrong uri:

```
Root_domain/productos-decoracion/iluminacion-interior
```

"Interior illumination" (iluminación interior) is a subcategory of "Illumination" and the uri doesn’t show it, it should be:
Root_domain/productos-decoracion/iluminacion/iluminacion-interior

This problems happens with all the other posts that have a top category and a subcategory.

**PROBLEM 2:**

The second problems comes when I click on breadcrumb link “Productos decoración” of many posts or categories pages, for instance here (`Root_domain/productos-decoracion/iluminacion/iluminacion-interior/crea-ambientes-interior-acogedores`
). Instead of bring to Root_domain/productos-decoracion (that’s what i want) it adds `%field%` to the end of the uri. `%field%` comes from functions.php code included above.

I've tried everything but with no success. I would really appreciate any help to fix this problems.

Answer (score 1):

After many headaches, I've spent days and hours finding a solution. I've find a solution for two problems commented above. I hope it helps to someone:

**PROBLEM 1**:
I realized that when I changed Permalink to Plain (wordpress admin > settings > permalink > Plain) and when I click in Breadcrumb link "iluminacion interior" it works OK (no more 404 error page). I tried the same in others subcategory's archive page and It works OK also. But I want "pretty permarlinks" I don't want this kind of url: ../?producto=crea-ambientes-interior-acogedores, so I’ve rewritten "/%category%/%postname%.html" in permarlinks > Custom Structure.

So the problem was that servers doesn't understand "pretty permalinks: /%category%/%postname%.html", then servers returns 404 error in subcategory's archives page when WordPress request this kind of url:
rootdomain.es/productos-decoracion/iluminacion/iluminacion-interior
To solve the problem I've added $newRules in function mmp_rewrite_rules in function.php, so the servers can understand WordPress requests. This is the new function mmp_rewrite_rules http://pastebin.com/AMELcM6r
I've done the same for the other CPT Proyectos.

**PROBLEM 2**:
This problem was easier to solve. I replace `‘has_archive’ => true,` for `‘has_archive’ => ‘productos-decoracion’,` in `my_custom_post_product()` function. `’productos-decoracion’` is the slug for the parent archive page. I do the same with proyectos CPT.

Now parent archive page url will be: …/productos-decoracion, no more .../productos-decoracion/%field%. Now we must create two file named: “archive-producto.php” and “archive-portfolio.php” (archive-CPT NAME.php) to show the content of parent archive pages.
That’s all.

Comment: Any chance we can get an updated link? The paste has expired. Even better, if you could paste here or update your post :)